# Compose a button to use in various parts of my project

Tags: android, android-xml, android-components

I've a button and i need to use this same button with same proprieties in all my projects and i want to create a component to just call this component and if i need to change my button, change in just one class do change all the uses.

I have this button:

```
<br.com.simplepass.loading_button_lib.customViews.CircularProgressButton
            android:id="@+id/createMatch"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:spinning_bar_width="4dp"
            app:spinning_bar_color="#FFF"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/createMatch"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:spinning_bar_padding="6dp"/>
```

I create a class extending CircularProgressButton but some proprieties i don't have ideia how to access in the code. The proprieties with app: for example.

Merging two questions, how i make a component with a layout with various itens?

for example:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <Toolbar/>
   <LinearLayout/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to compose this xml in a class to call and get all this itens in all the layouts using my custom class.

```
<MyLinearLayout>
...
</MyLinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some proprieties i don't have ideia how to access in the code. The proprieties with app: for example.

[Have a look here.](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)
You will have to subclass a View and provide a constructor that takes a Context and AttributeSet.

```
class CircleView extends View {

    private String mTitleText = "Your default title";

    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // You can and should also pass a style as third argument
        final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleView, 0, 0);

        if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.CircleView_titleText)) {
            mTitleText = a.getString(R.styleable.CircleView_titleText);
        }

        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

You might have noticed the use of `R.styleable.CircleView_titleText` in my example. Before using custom attributes, you have to tell the compiler about them. This is achieved by adding a `.xml` defining your attributes and their expected format.

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CircleView">
        <attr name="titleText" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

> how i make a component with a layout with various itens?

[Reusable Layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) is probably what you are looking for.

An example of this would be to define a custom toolbar as `toolbar.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e40056"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
    />
```

and then `include` it in other views:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/myToolbarId"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, i'll take a look!

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source code for [ProgressBar](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java), you'll see that you can use a `TypedArray` to retrieve styled attributes from the XML `AttributeSet`.

```
public ProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    ...
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.ProgressBar, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    ...
    // this is where we get the drawable that is specified in the XML
    final Drawable progressDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.ProgressBar_progressDrawable);
    ...
}
```

You can do the same to get the `app` attributes you're looking for, but some of the attributes are marked as internal. In those cases I would consider overriding them in `res/values/attrs.xml` because they may change.

***Note: progressDrawable is not necessarily internal, I just used it as an example***

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ProgressBar">
        <attr name="progressDrawable"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

As for your second question, I'm not sure if you want to extend `LinearLayout` (which I would advise against due to the fact that you would have to write code to create views) or simply reuse the `LinearLayout` with the views inside it.

If it's the latter, then you can just make an XML file with just your `LinearLayout` inside of it with the appropriate children, let's call it `myLayout.xml`. Then, in your other XML files you can just place it in like so:

myLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout>
   <Toolbar/>
   <LinearLayout/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>

    <include layout="@layout/myLayout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! i'll take a look